# iife vs simple statement behavior with document.title

Tags: javascript, bookmarklet

I was looking for a way to change the current page tab's title using a javascript bookmarklet.

I initially tried a simple statement but it was actually navigating me to a new page which contained only the title. I then found the same code but wrapped around as an iife.

Basically I am trying to understand the different between this:

```
javascript: document.title="title";
```

And this:

```
javascript: (function(){document.title="title";})();
```

Would someone kindly explain why the first statement navigates from the page and the second iife statement actually changes the title?

Comment: I'm wondering about that behaviour. For me both do the same. No navigation to another page. Where and how do you use that.

Comment: Both will do the same behavior. would be happy if you can provide us more code.

Comment: @L.Yogev It’s all the code you need. I can reproduce the behavior in Firefox Nightly 70.0a1. You can select each code snippet and drag-and-drop them in your bookmarks to create a bookmarklet; then just click on it.

Comment: The return value is different. Try `void (document.title="title")`.

Comment: Hi kmgt, I tried both of them as bookmarklets in Chrome Version 76.0.3809.100

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's basically just what bookmarklets do - if the expression that follows the `javascript:` resolves to something other than `undefined` (such as a string), the current page will be replaced. So, one option to run arbitrary Javascript is to run an IIFE that doesn't return anything. More explanation available [here](https://2ality.com/2011/06/implementing-bookmarklets.html).

The behavior may vary across browsers.

Another option is to use the comma operator:

```
javascript: (document.title = 'www.google.com', undefined)
```

For any code that isn't extremely trivial, you might consider using a userscript (like with [Tampermonkey](https://www.tampermonkey.net/)) instead of a bookmarklet, it'll probably be more manageable.

Comment: Or maybe better suited here, the `void` operator.

Comment: Thanks a lot for this! I was thinking about javascript bookmarklets in a different way and completely forgot that they are ultimately simple web shortcuts.